# Why do I get this error and how to solve it?

Tags: python

I'm doing an OOP exercise and I can't fix this error. If someone could help me and check if I am correct in my code it would be very helpful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 12, in <module>
    baldosa.rotar(270, "horario")
AttributeError: 'Baldosa' object has no attribute 'rotar'
```

```
class Camino:
    def __init__(self,extremos,color):
        
        self.extremos = extremos
        self.color = color
        self.conquistado = False
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        return "Camino: extremos =" + " " + str(self.extremos) + ", " + "color = " + self.color
        
    def rotar(self,grados,sentido):
        self.grados = grados
        self.sentido = sentido
        
        for i in range(0,2):
            
            if sentido == "horario":
                if grados == 90:
                    
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"
                        
                elif grados == 180:
                    
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"
                        
                elif grados == 270:
                    
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"
                        
            elif sentido == "antihorario" :
                
                if grados == 90:
                
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                    
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"
                        
                elif grados == 180:
                    
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"
                        
                elif grados == 270:
                    
                    if self.extremos[i] == "N":
                        self.extremos[i] = "E"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "O":
                        self.extremos[i] = "N"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "S":
                        self.extremos[i] = "O"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "E":
                        self.extremos[i] = "S"
                        
                    elif self.extremos[i] == "F":
                        self.extremos[i] = "F"

# Crea tu clase Baldosa
class Baldosa:
    
    def __init__(self,caminos):
        
        self.caminos = caminos
        
        for cantidad in range(len(caminos)):
            cantidad += 1
            
    def camino(self,fila,col):
        
        self.fila = fila
        self.col = col
        
        return "Baldosa: Num. de Caminos =" + str(self.camino) + "Ubicacion =" + "("+ str(self.fila) + "," + str(self.col) + ")"
```

Comment: Would you please show us your main.py, especially line 12 and its surroundings?

Comment: There is not enough code in your question to answer it.

Comment: `Camino` has a `rotar` method; `Baldosa` does not.  As `Baldosa` appears to be wrapper around a list of `Camino` objects, I suspect you want something like `baldosa.caminos[i].rotar(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You get this message because you create an instance of the class Baldosa and then attempt to execute the `rotar` method. You only defined it for instances of the class Camino because this is written inside the Camino class.
So either add the `rotar` method to the Baldosa class or create an instance of the Camina class i.e.

```
camino = Camino()
camino.rotar(270, "horario")
```